# Secure data access to RESTful API

Tags: security, authentication, rest

I figured this has been answered before, but a quick [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=secure+data+access+API) didn't yield anything.

I have a private API that is locked down by an APIKey. This key needs to be passed for each request. With this key you can access any part of the API. Obviously that's pretty *open*. For the most part this is acceptable. However, there are cases where I want to ensure that the request is sent by the *owner* of the data.

For example, consider an *update* or *delete* request. You shouldn't be able to make this request for someone else's data. So in addition to the APIKey, I'd like to have something else to ensure that this user making the request is *authorized* to perform that action.

I could require that an *ownerID* be passed with such request. But that's quickly forged. So what have I gained.

I am interested to hear what other members of SO have implemented in these situations. Individual APIKeys? Dual-authorization?

If it matters, my API follows the REST architecture and is developed with PHP/Apache.

Answer (score 0):

API keys should be unique per user. This will verify the user and that they should have access to the data.

If you want to be even more secure you can have that api secret be used as a refresh token that can be used to retrieve an access token with an automated expiration.

SSL for all requests is also suggested.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *refresh token*.

Answer (score 0):

Each API user has a unique API key.  This key identifies them as a single user of the system.  When dealing with more sensitive data, I've used [client side certificates](http://blog.nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi) for auth, however Basic Auth + requiring SSL is usually sufficient.

When the request comes in, map the API key to the user and then determine if that user "owns" the resource they are trying to interact with.

The whole "determine the owner" part is a separate issue that can be tricky to do nicely in an API depending on how well the system was built.  I can share how we've done that in the past as well, but figured that's a bit off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you should consider using Oauth. In summary this is how it should work.

Each application making the API calls will need the respective application level APIkey for authorization through the Oauth process. Apikey here would just represent the application (client) identity.

Each end-user associated with the usage must authenticate themselves separately (independent of the apikey) during the Oauth authorization process. The users identity, associated context such as scope of authorization is then encoded into a token called access token.

Once the application obtains this access token, all subsequent API calls to access resources should use the access token, until expiry.

On the API implementation side, the access token validation should reveal the end-user context (including the scope of access that is granted during the Oauth process) and hence the access/authorization to use a specific resource can be managed by the resource server.